# Swift 2.0 Error Handling Shows warning

Tags: ios, swift2

How to remove this warning swift 2.0?

[image]

Comment: Delete the try/catch as the method you are calling does not throw any exceptions

Comment: if any error occur with executeUpdate() then how can i handle it?

Comment: I don't know. You have to look at the documentation for that method. Try/catch is new with Swift 2 so many frameworks do not use it

Comment: i already tried to found solution from documentation for that warning but not get so i make post.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use error handling since apparently .executeUpdate does not throw any error so you can remove the do try catch and just call database.executeUpdate